# Adding [InitializeSimpleMembership] to my MVC controller asks me to generate a new class.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created the following Controller and Method to back up my database:

```
namespace WebUx.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    //[InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class BackupController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult BackupDatabase()
        {
            var dbPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DBBackup.bak");
            using (var db = new TestDBContext())
            {
                var cmd = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK='{1}' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME='DbBackups', MEDIADESCRIPTION='Media set for {0} database';"
                    , "TesteDB", dbPath);
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
            }

            return new FilePathResult(dbPath, "application/octet-stream");
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to run this I get the following message:

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
```

I saw that one solution on Stackoverflow was to add: [InitializeSimpleMembership]  I added this but it tells it cannot find the class and asks me to generate one.

Can someone explain what this means?

Comment: Do you have `InitializeSimpleMembership.cs` file in `Filters` folder of your project?

Comment: No I don't have that. I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: So your problem is because of you didn't configure simple membership correctly. Perform some searches about `Configuring simple membership to use existing database`...

Answer (score 0):

There is an other easier way to fix this problem
You can do this by creating a "_AppStart.cshtml" in the root of your project.

with the following content:

```
@{
    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ConnectionString", "User", "Id",
                                                 "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
}
```

The parameters for "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" are:

1. name of the connectionstring.
2. name of the table containing the users
3. PrimairyKey of the users table
4. Field name for username